# How can i Scan if a process is Opened in another Thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, process

Basically I have a WPF application Where the user Write A process Name  , 
Then a new Thread start where it keeps scanning if the process is Opened yet or not , The Thread will be Alive untill the process is Found .. So i can Get the handle and write The Memory !

```
 private void scanBtn_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread s = new Thread(( ) => {

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(( ) =>
            { 
                scanner(pName.Text);
            }));

        });


        try
        {

            if (pName.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                InfoTxt.Text = "[ WAITING FOR PROCESS TO OPEN ]";


                s.Start();
                pName.IsEnabled = false;
                if (!s.IsAlive)
                {
                    pName.IsEnabled = true;
                    InfoTxt.Text = "[ FOUND ]";
                    Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName(pName.Text)[0];


                }                                     
            }
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

  private static void scanner ( string procName)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Process s = SeekProcName(procName);
            if (s != null) break;

        }
    }

    private static Process SeekProcName(string pName)
    {
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle != (IntPtr)0).ToArray();
        Process f = null;

        foreach (var item in procs)
        {
            if (item.ProcessName.ToLower() == pName.ToLower())
            {
                f = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        return f;
    }
```

Comment: In your scanner thread why not trigger an event that you subscribe to in your main thread that tells you when it is done?

Comment: That `s` thread will do absolutely nothing. By calling `Dispatcher.Invoke` it's trying to execute a delegate on the UI thread. It's no different than just calling `scanner(pName.Text);` in the event handler. Why use such complicated code instead of a simple `await Task.Run(()=>SeekProcName(procName))`? You can put that in a loop in the event handler itself

Comment: Your new thread is pointless, all you do is dispatch a blocking infinite loop back onto the main thread. It would be much better just to use timer and check if the process exists.

Comment: See the [Remarks on MainWindowHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=netframework-4.8#remarks): *If you have just started a process and want to use its main window handle, consider using the WaitForInputIdle method to allow the process to finish starting, ensuring that the main window handle has been created.*

Comment: I forgot to say that im just A begginer in the Thread Notions !
@PanagiotisKanavos I Tried this : 
 `Process sProc = null;
            Thread s = new Thread(async( ) => {
                sProc =  await Task.Run(( ) => SeekProcName(pName.Text));
            });`

but it shoots me with error saying : ** The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**

Answer (score 0):

The `s` thread is trying to run a delegate on the UI thread, which means it's no different than calling `SeekProcName(procName)` in the event handler directly.

It would be better to use `Task.Run` and `async/await` to run the check in a background thread. When `await` returns, execution resumes in the UI thread which means the UI can be updated without requiring `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`

```
private async void scanBtn_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InfoTxt.Text = "[ WAITING FOR PROCESS TO OPEN ]";
    //Read the textbox contets *before* starting the task
    var name=pName.Text;

    var p=await Task.Run(()=>SeekProcName(name));
    if (p!=null)
    {
        InfoTxt.Text = "[ FOUND ]";
    }
}
```

This can be called in a loop, with a small delay between iterations, without blocking the UI thread :

```
private async void scanBtn_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while(someCondition)
    {
        InfoTxt.Text = "[ WAITING FOR PROCESS TO OPEN ]";
        var name=pName.Text;
        var p=await Task.Run(()=>SeekProcName(name));
        if (p!=null)
        {
            InfoTxt.Text = "[ FOUND ]";
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still Same Problem as i Said above : it throws an InvalidOperationException on the SeekProcName(pName.Text) part saying : 
Message : The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: @0x544D oops, fixed. You can't even read from a textbox from another thread, much less write to it